# Retrieve a array from json and generate a csv file

Tags: python, json

I am retrieving this data from API and it comes in JSON format. I only need the certain portion of the data and ignore all other data. Generate a csv file that look like my "Output.csv". My final aim to generate a csv file from json data.

JSON look like this:

```
   {
        "apiVersion": "3.0",
        "loggedInUser": {
            "id": "api@api.com",
            "unid": "192",
            "Access": [],
            "user": [],
            "local": {
                "id": 1,
                "dateFormat": "yyyy/dd/mm",
                "languageTag": "en-IR"
            }
        
        },
            "results":[
           {
              "id":"Random_Company_57",
              "unid":"75",
              "Access": [],
              "user": [],
             "local": {
                "id": 1,
                "dateFormat": "dd/MM/yy",
                "languageTag": "ne-UA"
            }
              "preferredLanguage":"IN",
              "prefName":"Christmas Bells",
              
           },
           {
              "id":"xyz.abc@safe.net",
              "unid":"98",
              "Access": [],
              "user": [],
            "local": {
                "id": 2,
                "dateFormat": "MM/DD/yy",
                "languageTag": "ne-UK"
            },
              "preferredLanguage":"en-CH",
              "prefName":"Christmas Bells",
              
           }
        ]
    }
```

My Output CSV("Output CSV") look like this:

```
id,unid,id,dateFormat,languageTag
Random_Company_57,75,1,dd/MM/yy,ne-AU
xyz.abc@safe.net,98,2,MM/DD/yy,ne-UK
```

My python code:

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process some integers.")
parser.add_argument("-path_save", help="define where to save the file")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="display processing information")

start = time.time()

def GetUsers(URL, endPoint, path_save, verbose):
    response = requests.get(URL, auth=('api@api.net', '1234'),
                            headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'key': 'Hb65OJBrrtV',
    })
    print(endPoint, response)
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(response.json()["results"])["local"]
    item_list=[]
    for item in df3:
        print(item)
        item_details = {"id":None, "dateFormat":None, "languageTag":None}
        item_details['id'] = item['id']
        item_details['dateFormat'] = item['dateFormat']
        item_details['languageTag'] = item['languageTag']
        item_list.append(item_details)
    print(item_list[0])
    item_list[0].to_csv('change.csv',index=False)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path_save = Path(args.path_save)
    verbose = args.verbose    
    endPoint = ['users']
    for endPt in endPoint:
        URL = "https://api.com/v95/" + endPt
        GetUsers(URL, endPt, path_save, verbose)  
    print("Processed time:", time.time() - start)  # Total Time
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process some integers.")
parser.add_argument("-path_save", help="define where to save the file")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="display processing information")

start = time.time()

def GetUsers(URL, endPoint, path_save, verbose):
    response = requests.get(URL, auth=('api@api.net', '1234'),
                            headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'key': 'Hb65OJBrrtV',
    })
    print(endPoint, response)

    res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'unid', 'local_id', 'dateFormat', 'languageTag'])

    for item in response.json()['results']:
        res = res.append(
            {
                'id': item['id'],
                'unid': item['unid'],
                'local_id': item['local']['id'],
                'dateFormat': item['local']['dateFormat'],
                'languageTag': item['local']['languageTag']
            },
            ignore_index=True
        )

    res.to_csv('change.csv', index=False)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path_save = Path(args.path_save)
    verbose = args.verbose    
    endPoint = ['users']
    for endPt in endPoint:
        URL = "https://api.com/v95/" + endPt
        GetUsers(URL, endPt, path_save, verbose)  
    print("Processed time:", time.time() - start)  # Total Time
```